# Is there a way to connect to a specific instance of Oracle server?

Tags: oracle, toad

I am not sure if I am using the right terminology, but I noticed while logged into OEM that my Oracle database server is set up with three instances and it seems to randomly pick one when I log in. Is there a way to update tnsnames to connect to a specific instance or do it in the New Connection window in Toad? I'm hoping I can kill a particular session that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question- in the TNSNames file, you can add an INSTANCE_NAME part like this. I did not figure out how to do it without a TNSNames file.

```
database =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (SDU=32767)
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server.name)(PORT = 1521)(SEND_BUF_SIZE = 98304)(RECV_BUF_SIZE = 98304))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
       (INSTANCE_NAME = instance_name)
      (SERVICE_NAME = service_name)
    )
 )
```

As @ik_zelf posted, you can query for which instance you're on using this:

```
select sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, yes you can. If you know on which server the instance is located, you could specify that host with the oracle service name that is running there.
Using `select instance_name, host_name, logins, status from v$instance;`
you can find out on which instance on which machine your current session is located.

You can find the other instances by querying gv$instance.

If you have no privileges on [g]v$instance you might want to try `select sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') from dual;` but this only works for the current instance.

A lot depends on the configuration that is running.

Comment: That last select query was very handy! I couldn't figure out which instance I was in and then realized after running that a few times, that Toad was adding the number in brackets next to the database name. I then learned how to update the tnsnames file for an instance_name and got conntected!